# Php returns decrypted string in unreadable format

Tags: php, encryption

I have an application where i need to convert a  user's name into encrypted format and then decrypt it in php.My encryption code works well. But at php side decrypted string always contains two to three additional characters in unreadable format.I just dont understand from where it is taking these additional characters?. Is it anything related with padding?
I am posting android code and php code.

**Android side code**:

```
public String encryptStringWithAES(String Message) throws Exception {

    String key = "123456789abcdefg";

    String iv = "1234567890123456";

    String padding = "ZeroBytePadding";


    SecretKeySpec spec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF8"), "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/" + padding);



    IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());


    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, spec, ivspec);

    byte[] array = cipher.doFinal(Message.getBytes());

    System.out.println("encrypted ARRAY LENGHT:" + array.length);

    String encoded_string = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(array, 0,
    array.length, Base64.NO_PADDING);

    System.out.println("Requested encoded string: " + encoded_string);
    return encoded_string;

}
```

**PHP side code:**

```
$key_for_AES='123456789abcdefg';

$iv='1234567890123456';



$message=$_POST['msg'];

$decoded_string=base64_decode($message);

$decrypted_string=mcrypt_decrypt('rijndael-128',$key_for_AES, $decoded_string,'cbc',$iv);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably have character encoding issues. Android code uses [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) for string encoding. Because of that make sure that entire data flow from android to php is using this encoding.

My concrete advice for you would be to check encoding of the php script file. You also have to determine if UTF-8 encoding is with BOM or without it.

Edit:

When I say "encoding" I think about "[character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)". Code in android responsible for character encoding is probably this:

```
key.getBytes("UTF8")
```

I don't know which editor you are using but you should check what character encoding is set for php script file you are using. Make sure it's UTF-8. And test both with BOM and without it because I am not sure what andorid is using.

Comment: thax for you replay. I first tried just encoding and decoding stuff . i.e encoded the string with base64 in android and decode it in php . and it works well.however when i try to use constant Base64.SAFE_URL or any other constant i get less or more characters in unreadable format.

Comment: original string=testing is mandatory    encrypted string=m+0nVREKQweWMeWhR0RnevVJmSDi decrypted string=testing is mandatory��

Comment: After lots of trial and error , i got my code working finally. The problem was related to the padding .After unpadding the string in php . i got the exact output.Any ways thax a lot everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar programming experience recently with C# and PHP.

It may be the decrypted object contains null characters. You can try stripping them. I also strip out carriage returns from the end of the string:

```
$decrypted_string = str_replace("\0", "", $Decrypted);
$decrypted_string = str_replace("\r", "", $Decrypted);
$decrypted_string = str_replace("\n", "", $Decrypted);
```